# Tips for improving performance of a 2d image 'tracing' CUDA kernel?

Tags: performance, image-processing, optimization, cuda

Can you give me some tips to optimize this CUDA code?

I'm running this on a device with compute capability 1.3 (I need it for a Tesla C1060 although I'm testing it now on a GTX 260 which has the same compute capability) and I have several kernels like the one below. The number of threads I need to execute this kernel is given by `long SUM` and depends on `size_t M` and `size_t N` which are the dimensions of a rectangular image received as parameter it can vary greatly from `50x50` to `10000x10000` in pixels or more. Although I'm mostly interested in working the bigger images with Cuda.

Now each image has to be traced in all directions and angles and some computations must be done over the values extracted from the tracing. So, for example, for a `500x500` image I need `229080 threads` computing that kernel below which is the value of SUM (that's why I check that the thread id `idHilo` doesn't go over it). I copied several arrays into the global memory of the device one after another since I need to access them for the calculations all of length `SUM`. Like this

```
cudaMemcpy(xb_cuda,xb_host,(SUM*sizeof(long)),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaMemcpy(yb_cuda,yb_host,(SUM*sizeof(long)),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

...etc
```

So each value of every array can be accessed by one thread. All are done before the kernel calls. According to the Cuda Profiler on Nsight the highest memcopy duration is `246.016 us` for a `500x500` image so that is not taking so long.

But the kernels like the one I copied below are taking too long for any practical use (3.25 seconds according to the Cuda profiler for the kernel below for a 500x500 image and 5.052 seconds for the kernel with the highest duration) so I need to see if I can optimize them.

I arrange the data this way

First the block dimension

```
dim3 dimBlock(256,1,1);
```

then the number of blocks per Grid

```
dim3 dimGrid((SUM+255)/256);
```

For a number of `895 blocks` for a `500x500` image.

I'm not sure how to use coalescing and shared memory in my case or even if it's a good idea to call the kernel several times with different portions of the data. The data is independent one from the other so I could in theory call that kernel several times and not with the 229080 threads all at once if needs be.

Now take into account that the outer `for` loop

```
for(t=15;t<=tendbegin_cuda[idHilo]-15;t++){
```

depends on

```
tendbegin_cuda[idHilo]
```

the value of which depends on each thread but most threads have similar values for it.

According to the Cuda Profiler the Global Store Efficiency is of `0.619` and the Global Load Efficiency is `0.951` for this kernel. Other kernels have similar values .

Is that good? bad? how can I interpret those values? Sadly the devices of compute capability 1.3 don't provide other useful info for assessing the code like the Multiprocessor and Kernel Memory or Instruction analysis. The only results I get after the analysis is "Low Global Memory Store Efficiency" and "Low Global Memory Load Efficiency" but I'm not sure how I can optimize those.

```
void __global__ t21_trazo(long SUM,int cT, double Bn, size_t M, size_t N, float* imagen_cuda, double* vector_trazo_cuda, long* xb_cuda, long* yb_cuda, long* xinc_cuda, long* yinc_cuda, long* tbegin_cuda, long* tendbegin_cuda){

long xi;
long yi;
int t;
int k;
int a;
int ji;
long idHilo=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;

int neighborhood[31];
int v=0;

if(idHilo<SUM){

    for(t=15;t<=tendbegin_cuda[idHilo]-15;t++){

        xi = xb_cuda[idHilo] + floor((double)t*xinc_cuda[idHilo]);
        yi = yb_cuda[idHilo] + floor((double)t*yinc_cuda[idHilo]);
        neighborhood[v]=floor(xi/Bn);
        ji=floor(yi/Bn);

        if(fabs((double)neighborhood[v]) < M && fabs((double)ji)<N)
        {
            if(tendbegin_cuda[idHilo]>30 && v==30){

                if(t==0)
                vector_trazo_cuda[20+idHilo*31]=0;

                for(k=1;k<=15;k++)
                vector_trazo_cuda[20+idHilo*31]=vector_trazo_cuda[20+idHilo*31]+fabs(imagen_cuda[ji*M+(neighborhood[v-(15+k)])]-
                            imagen_cuda[ji*M+(neighborhood[v-(15-k)])]);


                for(a=0;a<30;a++)
                neighborhood[a]=neighborhood[a+1];

                v=v-1;
            }

            v=v+1;
        }
    }
}

}
```

EDIT:

Changing the DP flops for SP flops only slightly improved the duration. Loop unrolling the inner loops practically didn't help.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are doing this calculation in double precision floating point?

Comment: Well the CPU version gives results in double precision floating point so I figured that to get the same results I would try it. Although maybe I can use floats instead. Would that help?

Comment: There is a 8 times arithmetic throughput difference and 2 times memory bandwidth difference between using single and double precision on your C1060. It isn't the main source of your problem, but it won't hurt.

Comment: I replicated the kernel with single precision flops (using floorf, fabsf, Bn and vector_trazo_cuda as float) and it's only slightly faster from 3.25 s to 3.177 s. Strangely enough if I declare vector_trazo_cuda as float but leave the floor and fabs functions for doubles and Bn as double it improves performance more not by much but something: 3.075 s. I tried several runs and it's always faster than the overall single precision one. I also tried loop unrolling the inner loops but the performance increase with the first is minimal and with the second is null I guess the compiler did it before.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the unstructured answer, I'm just going to throw out some generally useful comments with references to your code to make this more useful to others.

Algorithm changes are always number one for optimizing. Is there another way to solve the problem that requires less math/iterations/memory etc.

If precision is not a big concern, use floating point (or half precision floating point with newer architectures). Part of the reason it didn't affect your performance much when you briefly tried is because you're still using double precision calculations on your floating point data (fabs takes double, so if you use with float, it converts your float to a double, does double math, returns a double and converts to float, use fabsf).

If you don't need to use the absolute full precision of float use fast math (compiler option).

Multiply is much faster than divide (especially for full precision/non-fast math). Calculate 1/var outside the kernel and then multiply instead of dividing inside kernel.

Don't know if it gets optimized out, but you should use increment and decrement operators. v=v-1; could be v--; etc.

Casting to an int will truncate toward zero.  floor() will truncate toward negative infinite. you probably don't need explicit floor(), also, floorf() for float as above.  when you use it for the intermediate computations on integer types, they're already truncated. So you're converting to double and back for no reason. Use the appropriately typed function (abs, fabs, fabsf, etc.)

```
if(fabs((double)neighborhood[v]) < M && fabs((double)ji)<N)
change to
if(abs(neighborhood[v]) < M && abs(ji)<N)

vector_trazo_cuda[20+idHilo*31]=vector_trazo_cuda[20+idHilo*31]+
    fabs(imagen_cuda[ji*M+(neighborhood[v-(15+k)])]-
        imagen_cuda[ji*M+(neighborhood[v-(15-k)])]);
change to 
vector_trazo_cuda[20+idHilo*31] +=
    fabsf(imagen_cuda[ji*M+(neighborhood[v-(15+k)])]-
        imagen_cuda[ji*M+(neighborhood[v-(15-k)])]);
```

.

```
xi = xb_cuda[idHilo] + floor((double)t*xinc_cuda[idHilo]);
change to
xi = xb_cuda[idHilo] + t*xinc_cuda[idHilo];
```

The above line is needlessly complicated. In essence you are doing this,
convert t to double, 
convert xinc_cuda to double and multiply, 
floor it (returns double), 
convert xb_cuda to double and add, 
convert to long.

The new line will store the same result in much, much less time (also better because if you exceed the precision of double in the previous case, you would be rounding to a nearest power of 2).  ***Also, those four lines should be outside the for loop***...you don't need to recompute them if they don't depend on t. Together, i wouldn't be surprised if this cuts your run time by a factor of 10-30.

Your structure results in a lot of global memory reads, try to read once from global, handle calculations on local memory, and write once to global (if at all possible).

Compile with -lineinfo always. Makes profiling easier, and i haven't been able to assess any overhead whatsoever (using kernels in the 0.1 to 10ms execution time range).

Figure out with the profiler if you're compute or memory bound and devote time accordingly.

Try to allow the compiler use registers when possible, this is a big topic.

As always, don't change everything at once.  I typed all this out with compiling/testing so i may have an error.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running too many threads simultaneously. The optimum performance seems to come when you run the right number of threads: enough threads to keep busy, but not so many as to over-fragment the local memory available to each simultaneous thread.

Last fall I built a tutorial to investigate optimization of the Travelling Salesman problem (TSP) using CUDA with CUDAFY. The steps I went through in achieving a several-times speed-up from a published algorithm may be useful in guiding your endeavours, even though the problem domain is different. The tutorial and code is available at [CUDA Tuning with CUDAFY](https://cudafytuningtutorial.codeplex.com/).

Comment: OK thanks, I'll check it out. Although I've heard that the more threads you use the better since it keeps the device resources busy.

Comment: I was looking at your link and i found some interesting things. Also correct me if I'm wrong but even if I launch with 800+ blocks of 256 threads like I'm doing wouldn't only 32 threads run simultaneously? Will it make a difference if I put the kernel call on a loop and run smaller grid sizes each time?

Comment: You want to have enough threads so that memory latency disappears on average; however all queued threads must share the same limited local storage. Try halving or quartering your thread total and see if the time improves, and repeat until you find the optimum.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try some simpler enhancements first and then I'll try something like this.